# How does a PR Trigger work when a PR is created from feature to develop branch? Does the Build get triggered at destination branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Background: Develop branch doesnt have any ci/cd pipeline set. I've created a multi stage release pipeline at feature branch and is working fine till dev stage, QA stage depends on successful dev stage and a PR trigger. I have created a PR from feature to Develop branch. Does this PR trigger a build at Dev?

Comment: Can you share your release pipelines trigger configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this PR trigger a build at Dev?

For this issue,If there is no ci/cd pipeline on the develop branch, the pr from feature to the develop branch will not trigger the build on dev branch.

PR can trigger the build at the destination branch,the premise is that your branch has pipelines. If there is no pipeline on this branch, then the build policy in this branch is also not available.
[image]